# Java how to write generics

Tags: java, class, oop, object, generics

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T search(T[] a,T first,T last,T key)
{
    T result;
    if(first.compareTo(last)>0)
        result = -1;
    else{
        int mid = (Integer)(first+last)/2;
        if(key==a[mid])
            result = mid;
        else if(key<a[mid])
            result = search(a,first,mid - 1,key);
        else if(key>a[mid])
            result = search(a,mid+1,last,key);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is a recursive binary search that I am trying to write. I am trying to use generics but I am very naive in it. All of the errors that I encountered are type conversion errors. Except where it says (mid-1).There the error is "Inference variables T has incompatible bounds". I wanted to learn how to go about solving them.
    Thank You.

Comment: A comparable can't be cast to integer. Think string for example in it's place

Comment: Doesnot ring a bell brother..

Comment: your last and first are indexes in your array, so define them as integers, and that will fix your  method

Comment: public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T search(T[] a,int first,int last,T key) this way?

Comment: @Yourfavouritenoob yes, obviously tou need to change `first.compareTo(last)` to `a[first].compareTo(a[last])` as well

Comment: and `return -1` change to `return null`

Comment: i changed first and last back to int and (first>last) will work. Array indexes will always be integers. But the problem with result = -1; still remains

Comment: @Yourfavouritenoob if you are just starting out with generics, a good way to work it all out is to write the method as a non-generic method and then gradually see where you could re-use it and make those parts generic. The type argument `T` will represent a single type each time you call the method (i.e. it isn't as magic as your example code makes it appear). It is worth thinking about the different types that can be used and substituting `T` for that type... "So T is a Comparable<FizzNut> - does that work..."

Comment: I do understand that. Do arithmetic operations work the same in Generics. How do I correct this statement here. result = -1; where result is of type T.

Comment: Btw: maybe a good tip on how to write generics: Start by writing everything with concrete types, for example `String` instead of `T`. Once that works, turn every mention of a concrete type into some `T`. That's also what the compiler tries to ensure works in reverse: It's like thinking of a concrete type instead of T. That check fails because `mid - 1` is `Integer` but not necessarily the concrete type it was thinking of. You would have noticed that if you had written the method with some concrete type first, that's why I like doing that when I get confused by generics.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misunderstand the `Comparable` interface; just because something is comparable doesn't mean, that the cast to `Integer` will be successful. Or that you can use the `+` operator. If you are sure that you'll be able to add up your values, you may want to look at the [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) interface which offers a `intValue()` function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are doing right this is what you wanted to get:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T search(T[] sortedArray,int first,int last,T key)
{
    T result;
    if(first > last)
        result = null;
    else{
        int mid = (Integer)(first+last)/2;
        if(key.equals(sortedArray[mid]))
            result = sortedArray[mid];
        else if(key.compareTo(sortedArray[mid]) <0)
            result = search(sortedArray,first,mid - 1,key);
        else
            result = search(sortedArray,mid+1,last,key);
    }
    return result;
}
```

There seems to be a problem when 'first' == 'last' as the recursion would not stop there.
You should add a check for that:

```
    if(first == last)
    {
        if(sortedArray[first].equals(key))
        {
            return sortedArray[first]; 
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And do you really want to get the Object back that you just fed into the the algorithm as key?

If you wanted to get the index of the key in the array you will have to change the return value to int and :

- return -1 instead of null for an error
- return mid or first if you found the object.

Comment: Thanx.How do I return index, instead of value? wouldn't the same type conversion problem arise?

Comment: That last comment saved the day,I was on the first phase of learning generics.Just followed a tutorial without really knowing what I was doing. I looked back at my code, I did not really have to return an object. All I needed was the key and the array of type T. The rest are integers. Thank You for that last comment.